# How to fetch the backbone collection and pass to view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i am facing problem in backbone collection.

this is my router

```
    var LanguageRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'defaultaction',
        'section/:key': 'sectionview',
    }
});
```

collection is

```
 var LanguageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: LanguageModel,
    url: '/lang'
});
```

and app.js

```
 var initialize = function () {
    var language_router = new LanguageRouter(),
        parent_view = new ParentView(),
        list_collection = new LanguageCollection(),
        list_collection.fetch();
    language_router.on('route:defaultaction', function () {
        list_view = new LanguageListView({
            collection: list_collection,
            template: _.template(templates.languagelistsingle)
        });

    });
```

Here , after fetching the list_collection i tried passed the collection to language_view but i am getting empty collection only. How to fix this... Thanks in advance

Comment: `fetch` is asynchronous, are you sure the call has already been completed when you are checking it?

Comment: when i am checking console first calling router event then list_collection fetching .. i dont know how to fix

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is not synchronous, so you cannot call it in one line and use the return on the next line. The correct way using backbone is use listenTo or On (depending on the backbone version)

You could change this part:

```
list_collection = new LanguageCollection();
this.listenTo(list_collection, "sync", this.someFunction()); 
\\here we are listening the sync event that is automatically fired by backbone when a model or collection is synced with the server.

list_collection.fetch();


someFunction:function(){
    //Logic with the collection content...
}
```

To learn more about events, please take a read here: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Comment: but i want collection.. Now i am getting empty.

Comment: Inside 'someFunction' this.collection ?make sure that you're performing fetch(), and of course it is returning content. also make sure that your url is pointing to the correct api.

Comment: i cant because i need 15 reputation